# Javascript: Dynamically created button disappears?

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript. I want to dynamically create a new button when a user clicks on the "Create Element" button. The script creates a button but only for a fraction of second. Also the 'value' attribute is not set for the button.

If there is any theory behind the behavior please redirect me to the proper URL.

Here is the code :

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function doSomething(){     
        myButton = document.createElement("button");        
        myButton.setAttribute("value","New Button");        
        document.getElementById("myForm").appendChild(myButton);        
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="myForm">
        <button name="myButton" id="myButtonID" onclick="doSomething()">Create Element</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

A `<button>` element is a submit button by default - thus you're submitting the form, causing a reload of the page.

You'd need to use:

```
<button type="button" ...>...</button>
```

Or:

```
<input type="button" ...>
```

Comment: Just found this after hours of attempting to fix this bug. I cannot stress how grateful I am, 5 hours of my life are gone but at least I can go to sleep now :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Your onclick callback has to return false.

```
<button name="myButton" id="myButtonID" onclick="doSomething(); return false">
```

Answer (score 1):

i would not create the button that way. I would do something like this:

```
    myButton = document.createElement('input');
myButton.setAttribute("type","button");
```

Answer (score 0):

**As already mentioned before use "input" instead "button". Because "button" cause a postback with page refresh. By using "input" you won't get the postback**

// create new element in html page

```
function createElement_Click()
{
    
    // btn variable will contain a RAW html [<input></input>] object
    var btn = document.createElement("input");
    //So now we can manipulate its properties:
    btn.type = "button"; //equal to (<input type="button"></input>) in html

    //add some value to it
    btn.value = "Click Me";
    btn.id = "btnShow";
    btn.onclick = function() { ShowMessage(); };
    
    // step -1 put your newly created object into html
    document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(btn);


}

function ShowMessage() {
    alert("hello world");
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the following code:

btn.onclick ="ShowMessage()" ; //dosen't work
or
btn.onclick=ShowMessage(); //works but cause an alert("hello world") to fire right after creating a new element. And we don't want this to happen